# Clear the Internet Cache of a Windows 7 machine remotely

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, administrator

If I have admin access to another machine on the same domain, is there a way for me to remotely clear the internet cache on that machine? Or do I need to remotely access the desktop via RDP or something?

Answer (score 0):

There are many PowerShell scripts available to do that. Depending on your security config, you may need to enable remote PowerShell.

Example of a script that was tested on Windows 7 is [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Clear-Internet-Explorer-5ee32ff6)